# How to add dll reference in visual basic 6 using vb6 coding?

Tags: vb6, activex

I made one exe file in vb6 which is using the reference of one dll file. When I try that exe in other system i am getting following error :

> Error 429, Activex component cant create object

Please help me for the same.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550

Comment: Lots of [very similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Activex+component+cant+create+object), too many to choose just one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install that referenced DLL in the target machine and register it as per the authors instructions.

If you tell us what component/DLL/library it is, you may get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy your dll in %winsys%\system32\
registers -i mydll.dll

%winsys% = c:\windows
%winsys% = c:\winnt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this.

1) register the DLL that you have made. using - regsvr32

2) Find out ProgID for your dll project name, in registry (cmd  =regedit) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542719(v=vs.85).aspx

3) call CreateObject Function  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5(v=vs.90).aspx

Now that's programming :)